# Unclosed regular expression ReactJS Error

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error

```
class Lamp extends React.component {
     constructor(){
       super();
       this.state = {
       active: false
       };
     }
    toggleActive() {
       this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
    }
    render() {
         return (
                <div
                style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.active ? 
                this.props.color : "" }}>lampada
                <button onclick={() => this.toggleActive()}>on/off</button>
                </div>
         );
   }
}
React.render(<Lamp color="green" />, document.body);
```

I don't view anything when I open the index.html and the debug of chrome tell me: "*Unclosed regular expression*"

Answer (score 1):

You should use `react-dom` instead.

`ReactDOM.render(<Lamp color="green" />, document.body)`

```js
class Lamp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      active: false,
    }

    this.toggleActive = this.toggleActive.bind(this)
  }

  toggleActive() {
     this.setState({ active: !this.state.active })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.active ? 'green' : 'red' }}
      >
        lampada
        <button onClick={this.toggleActive}>on/off</button>
       </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Lamp />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I try to copy your answer but the system tell me always: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
on the line: *<div*

Comment: @Browserz maybe because there was a space between `<` and `Lamp` on `ReactDOM.render(...`